# Is the [raven] tag about Sentry or RavenDB?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Historically it seems that the [raven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raven) tag has been used for questions about the SDKs for [Sentry.io](https://sentry.io). However, if I remember correctly, a few months ago, [raven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raven) was converted to a sponsored tag equivalent to [ravendb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ravendb), while the tag description still refers to Sentry.

The majority of questions are still about Sentry but are all accompanied by the logo for RavenDB. As a Sentry employee I used to follow this tag anyway until the first RavenDB questions came in.

What should be done?

- Remove tag from RavenDB questions (we have [ravendb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ravendb) as equivalent)?
- Remove tag from Sentry questions (we have [sentry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sentry) as equivalent)?
- Remove tag from all questions (possibly blacklist) to clear all confusion?

Answer (score 2):

There are 124 questions out of 134, that are tagged along with [sentry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sentry), which makes it overwhelmingly clear that the tag is being used correctly for Sentry related questions. A quick glance at the [remaining 10 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Braven%5D+-%5Bsentry%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0) shows that just 4 of them are using the tag incorrectly.

The way to go here would be to just

1. retag the handful number of questions (done)
2. update the tag description to point to [ravendb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ravendb) for the Raven DB questions (done)
3. and change the sponsorship, unless ravendb wants to sponsor the sentry package.  (looks like it already has been removed).

It is not much of an issue now, unless this becomes a daily problem in the coming few days, at which point of time, we can revisit and rename the [raven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raven) tag. (I am not sure if you have already removed the tag from a majority of the questions, in which case, we would need to rename this tag as [raven-sentry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raven-sentry))